# How to convert jpeg image to base64 string or bytes in xamarin forms..?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, image-conversion

I am converting jpeg image to base 64 but every time i am getting different base64 string. So please tell me how i convert image to base64 so i will get same result every time. As i want to use that result to get hash value of Image.

Code:

```
    public byte[] GetImageStreamAsBytes(Stream input)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

To call above method i used

```
bytes = GetImageStreamAsBytes(stream);
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: public byte[] GetImageStreamAsBytes(Stream input)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

Comment: And to call this function i am using byte[] bytes = GetImageStreamAsBytes(stream);

Comment: There's a similar question posted in [xamafin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27743/image-to-base64-conversion)